# Proposal to drop "& Usage" from the site title — Proposition de raccourcir le titre du site en « French Language »

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

**Update 11/25: Thanks for your feedback! We're going to go ahead and drop "& Usage" from the site title.** The header image and the "official" language around the site (in the help center and about page, for example) should be updated within the next few days.

I know this community would like to see the site name be in French as well, but that's not a change we're prepared to make at this time.

---

I'm Laura, a product manager at Stack Exchange.

I wanted to let this community know that I've started a discussion over on Meta Stack Overflow about some general guidelines for naming our sites, specifically our language sites, going forward. Feel free to [read and discuss my post over there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names).

The gist of my proposal is that "& Usage" generally makes a site name longer and more difficult to say and type without adding much, if any, meaning.

**We'd like to rename existing Stack Exchange language sites to just "X Language" and drop "& Usage" from both existing sites and any new language sites we launch in the future.**

This means the header image on the site would simply read "French Language" rather than "French Language & Usage", and all of the official documentation would drop "& Usage" as well. The site URL would not change.

We've already done this with our Italian Language site (in private beta at the time of this writing), and [they were pleased](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/why-is-this-language-stack-exchange-site-named-italian-language-while-all-oth) [[read-only link](http://stackmobile.com/meta.italian/questions/60) for non-participants] with the simpler name. Until now, our language sites have followed the naming convention of "X Language & Usage Stack Exchange", but why? It seemed to make sense at the time, but as we've grown, it's become clear that "& Usage" isn't really necessary. A site about a particular language is, by definition, concerned with the usage of that language — that's where all the questions come from!

Before we actually make any changes to existing sites, I wanted to hear any concerns you might have. I feel like a shorter, simpler name is a big win for everyone, but please feel free to post concerns about this particular community here, or any general concerns over on [the main MSO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names).

---

[Ce qui suit est une traduction non officielle du message en anglais.]

Je suis Laura, chef de produit chez Stack Exchange.

J'ai lancé [une discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names) sur le site méta principal de Stack Exchange à propos des habitudes de nommage des [sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) de notre réseau, et en particulier des sites de langue.

En ce qui concerne ce site, dont le nom actuel est « French Language & Usage » [« Langue et usage du français » ou « Langue française et son usage », N.d.T.], l'essentiel de ma proposition consiste à supprimer la partie « & Usage », qui rallonge le nom sans vraiment rajouter d'information.

**Nous projetons de renommer tous les sites de langue, qui suivent actuellement le motif « X Language & Usage », en « X Language ».**

Nous l'avons déjà fait pour notre tout nouveau site d'italien (actuellement en béta privée), et [la communauté aime le nom plus simple](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/why-is-this-language-stack-exchange-site-named-italian-language-while-all-oth) [[lien en lecture seule](http://stackmobile.com/meta.italian/questions/60) pour les non-participants]. Jusqu'à présent, tous nos sites de langue ont suivi le motif « X Language & Usage », et à l'époque ceci nous paraissait normal. Mais en fin de compte, pourquoi « & Usage » ? Cette partie n'est pas utile : par définition, un site à propos d'une langue aborde nécessairement son usage de manière essentielle — toute question de langue touche à son usage !

Avant de toucher aux sites existants, je suis à l'écoute de vos objections éventuelle. Je pense qu'un nom plus court et plus simple serait un gain pour la communauté, mais si vous êtes d'un avis contraire, merci d'en faire part soit ici (si votre opinion concerne ce site en particulier) ou sur le [fil de discussion principal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names) (en anglais, pour des considérations plus générales).

**Mise à jour le 25/11: Nous allons supprimer la partie « & Usage » du nom du site**. Le texte et les images seront mis à jour d'ici quelques jours. Je suis consciente que cette communauté aimerait que le nom du site soit en français, mais nous ne sommes pas prêts à un tel changement.

Comment: “French Language” is poor branding. Who could ever recognize this as the name of a website? Were this change to occur, we'd have to explain that French Language is about French language and Meta French Language is about French Language. Crystal clear! (Notice: I'm not saying that *X Language & Usage* is the best choice either.)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Technically, the full name would be "French Language Stack Exchange" (the same way that technically, right now the full name is "French Language & Usage Stack Exchange"), though the header image would simply say "French Language". I do appreciate your concern here, but I don't think dropping "& Usage" introduces any new problems.

Answer (score 6):

My favorite name for this site would be “Langue française”. If the name has to be in English, I prefer “French Language” to “French Language & Usage”: I agree that the “and usage” part is redundant. Furthermore the current name is slightly awkward to translate into French, where the adjective *French* has to be placed after the noun, which makes it less visible.

We haven't done much promotion of the site (partly because the lack of a French interface deprives us of much of our potential audience), so really, only a few regulars would spot the name change anyway.

The only thing I like about the current name is the abbreviation FLU — FL is less recognizable among the Stack Exchange cognoscenti. But this isn't an important audience.

However, I do see value in naming the sites uniformly. My preference is for all sites to change. If English Language & Usage doesn't change, I'm not sure that it's such a good idea to change the other sites.

---

Dans l'idéal, ce site s'appellerait « Langue française »... Tant qu'à avoir un nom en anglais, je préfère « French language » au titre actuel, qui est effectivement redondant. De plus, l'expression complète « French language and usage » ne rend pas bien traduite en français : on peut dire « langue française et son usage », ou « langue et usage du français », mais comme contrairement à l'anglais l'adjectif est placé après le nom, celui-ci perd d'autant plus de visibilité en raison de la présence du nom supplémentaire.

Nous n'avons guère promu ce site (en partie parce que l'absence d'interface en français nous coupe d'une partie de notre public potentiel). Du coup, seul quelques visiteurs fréquents remarqueraient le changement de nom.

La seule chose que j'aime dans le nom actuel est l'abréviation FLU : FL est moins immédiatement reconnaissable. Mais ceci n'intéresse que quelques cognoscenti de Stack Exchange, ce n'est pas notre public principal.

Un bémol tout de même : je vois un intérêt certain à avoir des noms uniformes sur le réseau Stack Exchange. Ma préférence va à renommer tous les sites pour supprimer la partie « & Usage ». Si English Language & Usage ne doit pas bouger, je ne suis pas sûr qu'il soit judicieux de renommer les autres.

Comment: I'm curious, why does your support for the name change hinge on whether English Language & Usage changes? There are two English sites (Langauge & Usage, and Language Learners), which is a rather compelling reason to make an exception for them – at least, I think it is, but I'm interested if/why you disagree.

Comment: @Laura I'm composing a post on meta.ELU. ELL is about the English language and its usage (whatever nuance “and its usage” brings), so the “& Usage” part does nothing to distinguish the two sites. If you want to differentiate the sites, add something to the ELU name that does not apply to ELL.

Comment: @Laura: English Language learners is essentially, if not entirely, about English **usage**, so your point does not stand. Non usage questions (etymology, history of the language tags, etc.) are asked by those who already have a great command of the language on EL&U.