# Acronyme pour remplacer FL&U

Tags: discussion

Maintenant que le "*& Usage*" [a été retiré](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/503/1129), quel acronyme utiliser en lieu et place de *FL&U*?

J'ai bien quelques idées, mais aucune ne me convainc vraiment:

- *FL* : trop court à mon avis
- *FL.SX* (sur le modèle de *TeX.SX*, utilisé fréquemment sur [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)) : renforce l'appartenance au réseau StackExchange, mais pas vraiment évident à comprendre
- french.sx : ressemble trop à un vrai nom de domaine

D'autres propositions?

Comment: Thanks fr asking, I wondered the same exactly. In particular, how to say "welcome to FL&U", now ?

Answer (score 6):

J'ai commencé à utiliser **fr.SE** (ou fr.se, ou à la rigueur FR.SE mais ça donne l'impression que FR est un sigle).

`fr` est le [code ISO 639](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) du français, et a en plus l'avantage de rappeler à la fois le nom français et le nom anglais du sujet.

Nos compagnons sont sur ce modèle [de.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/), [it.SE](https://italian.stackexchange.com/), [zh.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/), etc.

Answer (score 2):

J'utilise déjà *french.SE* quand je parle à d'autres StackExchangeurs, personne ne va s'imaginer pour autant qu'on vient de Suède. Quant à un nom entre nous, *FL* ne me pose pas de problème.

Answer (score 1):

F.SE : éviter le *French* en entier permettra de ne pas se reposer la question le jour où - enfin - l'interface sera localisée.

Ajout après la remarque d'Édouard :
Ou alors FR.SE (FR French/Français) qu'on pourrait prononcer /fʁɛ/. Ça ne permettrait cependant pas d'éviter la confusion avec un futur site de frison ou de frioulan (quoique frioulan se dise *furlan* en frioulan).

Comment: Après un parcours rapide, il semble que French Language est bien le seul site de SE commençant par F. En revanche, F.SE ne se prononce pas, c’est dommage.