# French Language & Francophonie ou French Language & Usages

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Suite au codicille de la *[réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/couper-les-cheveux-%C3%A0-quelquun-est-correct-pourtant-de-est-usit%C3%A9)* (honorée d'un bounty de Divulgâchâmes), j'en suis venu à proposer d'appeler ce site **French Language *& Francophonie***.

De nombreux arguments sont en filigrane dans la réponse, y compris pourquoi je souhaite remplacer *bêta* par *'& francophonie'*.

Au départ, c'est l'envie de dépasser la grammaire et les dictionnaires pour faire aimer la francophonie par ceux qui s'y intéresse.

---

English summary: I am proposing to rename this site from “French Language beta” to “French Language & Francophonie”. My primary motivation is to go beyond grammar and dictionaries and let interested people enjoy *francophonie*. Many arguments underscore [my answer to a main site question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/couper-les-cheveux-%C3%A0-quelquun-est-correct-pourtant-de-est-usit%C3%A9/14493#14493).

---

***EDIT*** Complément suite à la réponse de Chop

En effet, l'acception usuelle de francophonie n'est pas celle que j'avais en tête lorsque j'ai posé cette question.

Et pour rester dans le cadre du site je penche maintenant pour ***French Language & Usages*** avec un *s* final pour l'exception culturelle ou sans *s* ... à voter !

Et puis, toujours pour l'exception culturelle, on peut toujours rêver de remplacer *bêta* par "En cours d’agrément par les autorités de tutelle" ... ou *certainement* pas :) .

---

***EDIT*** Reaction to Chop's answer

Indeed, the usual meaning of "*francophonie*" is not the one I had in mind when asking this question.

And to stay within this site's scope, I know propose **French Language & Usages** with or without a final *S* for the cultural exception... To be voted!

Now, for cultural exception still, we can dream of replacing "beta" with "*En cours d'agrément par les autorités de tutelle*"... Or *definitely* not.

Comment: Le qualificatif « beta » restera tant que le site n'aura pas atteint un seuil de trafic (en principe un rythme soutenu de 10 questions/jour) et qu'un concepteur graphique n'aura pas eu le temps de créer une charte spécifique pour le site.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas l'intérêt d'ajouter « francophonie » au titre. Pourquoi mettre en avant cet aspect politique de la langue ?

Comment: @Gilles -- La francophonie n'est pas une politique, c'est l'***usage*** d'une langue, même si les politiciens se rendent compte que cet usage a besoin d'être encouragé ; il ne s'agit pas d'en faire la propagande, mais de montrer sa richesse sur un site qui a tendance à privilégier son étude académique, la variété des solutions orales n'est pas toujours évoquée et par conséquent les sens cachés ou induits rarement évoqués. Le problème est que je ne sais trop comment extraire les arguments qui sont dans la réponse en référence.

Comment: @Gilles C'est peut-être en élargissant les centres d'intérêt, en intégrant aussi l'oralité dans les réponses, en cherchant comment dépasser les limites que ce fameux *seuil* sera atteint.

Comment: @Gilles Le seuil est encore loin d'être atteint, mais s'il faut concevoir une charte graphique propre au site, je suis partant pour m'y coller.

Comment: @Chop La charte graphique est faite par des employés de Stack Exchange, sans demander l'avis des utilisateurs avant la version bêta. (Heureusement : tu t'imagines ce que ça peut donner, une charte graphique où des centaines de personnes donnent leur avis.) Ils sont débordés, donc si tu veux la faire, cette charte graphique, tu peux toujours postuler pour un emploi de *graphic designer*.

Comment: @Gilles Merci pour l'information.

Comment: @Gilles & cl-r Je passais par là, je me suis permis de traduire l'edit.

Comment: @cl-r Ma réponse n'est pas complète par rapport à votre question éditée. Peut-être faudrait-il la désaccepter afin de ne pas décourager d'éventuels participants ?

Comment: @Chop Je l'avais mise au vert, je la rentre à l'étable, en attendant les touristes, mais aussi pour vous laisser le temps d'éventuels compléments, d'éventuelles corrections. Je reste 'enthusiast' et commence à relire certaines de mes réponses, pour voir si un § *usage* est pertinent.

Comment: @Gilles Il est fort possible que nous puissions [nous débarrasser du « beta » sans rehaussement graphique personnalisé](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260754/208568).

Comment: @cl-r J'ai complété ma réponse suite à l'edit de la question, mais elle n'apporte au final aucune réponse définitive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seconde réponse pour la seconde proposition.

## TL;DR

- *Upvote* si **en faveur** d'un changement du nom pour *French language & Usage*.
- *Downvote* si **en défaveur**.

## *French language & Usage(s)*

Ceci est un changement probablement plus simple à justifier.

### L'existant : en faveur

Lors de l'analyse de l'existant (cf. [mon autre réponse](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/585/7224), on a vu que le nom complet d'[english.SX](https://english.stackexchange.com/) est *English Language & Usage*.

J'ai dit que, comme french.SX, english.SX a la particularité de porter sur une langue vivante parlée dans plusieurs parties du monde.

Selon la même logique, il me paraît alors effectivement possible d'envisager ce changement. Toujours en s'inspirant d'english.SX, la solution avec *Usage* au singulier serait à privilégier.

English me semble le modèle à privilégier. Il a deux avantages (possiblement liés) majeurs :

- il est dans la langue première des SX ;
- il n'est plus en bêta.

### L'existant : en défaveur

Par opposition, [russian.SX](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) et [italian.SX](https://italian.stackexchange.com/) s'appellent respectivement *Russian Language* et *Italian Language*.

Ainsi, même si le *& Usage* peut être justifié par english.SX, d'autres sites de langue n'en font pas usage. La question reste donc ouverte à l'appréciation de la majorité.

[Gilles](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles) nous rappelle en commentaire un peu l'histoire des sites de langues sur StackExchange :

> Les sites de langues sur Stack Exchange s'appelaient autrefois « X Language & Usage » et [sont passés à « X Language »](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/503/proposal-to-drop-usage-from-the-site-title-proposition-de-raccourcir-le-ti) (sauf [English Language & Usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), pour garder un acronyme bien distinct d'[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) — même si [c'est plutôt ELL.SE qui parle d'usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/a-conversation-about-language-site-names/4278#comment14051_4278)).

### L'utilisation concrète de french.SX

[cl-r](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/848/cl-r) le signale en commentaire :

> L'idée est d'encourager les réponses qui ajoutent quelque chose à la lecture des dictionnaires et des grammaires, un 'plus' donnant les usages soit 'académiques', soit dans la vie courante ou au bureau, soit argotiques... de simples témoignages de... la francophonie ! --- Les commentaires semblent très favorable à une évolution dans ce sens.

Il est vrai que nous pouvons observer de temps à autre des réponses qui précisent un vécu, une façon de parler la langue dans une région, parfois sans l'appui de référence autre que la vie de tous les jours.

On peut ainsi avoir des comparaisons sur l'utilisation ou la signification d'expressions qui varient en fonction de la contrée (par exemple France métropolitaine, Belgique et Québec).

Comment: L'anglais, l'espagnol, le portugais et aussi le français sont des langues transcontinentales et/ou transocéaniques, ce qui entraîne des *usages* vernaculaires qui enrichissent, complètent, poétisent leur 'mère'. Passer de *gros bêtas* à citoyens du monde en intégrant ces usages me semble une option favorable pour SX. ---  On pourrait aussi ajouter sur la page de FE.SX " ... et francophones enthousiastes (ou un mot de la même veine comme *passionnés*)".

Comment: Les sites de langues sur Stack Exchange s'appelaient autrefois « X Language & Usage » et [sont passés à « X Language »](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/503/proposal-to-drop-usage-from-the-site-title-proposition-de-raccourcir-le-ti) (sauf [english.se], pour garder un acronyme bien distinct d'[ell.se] — même si [c'est plutôt ELL.SE qui parle d'usage](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/a-conversation-about-language-site-names/4278#comment14051_4278)).

Comment: Merci @Gilles. Étant donnée la pertinence de ton commentaire, je me suis permis de l'intégrer à la réponse pour qu'il soit lu et préservé.

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR

- *Upvote* si **en défaveur** d'un changement du nom pour *French language & Francophonie*<sup>1</sup>
- *Downvote* si **en faveur**

## *French language &* Francophonie

Ce choix n'est pas transparent étant donné le périmètre de ce StackExchange.

### Les implications

#### Le périmètre

D'après [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francophonie) :

> La francophonie désigne l'ensemble des personnes et des institutions qui utilisent le français comme langue maternelle, langue d'usage, langue administrative, langue d'enseignement ou langue choisie.

Or la page d'acceuil de french.SX précise son périmètre actuel :

> *French Language Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the French language.*

La *langue* est au cœur de nos échanges. Qu'elle et ses usages varient selon les régions est un fait. Nous essayons déjà de prendre en compte les différences par la participation d'utilisateurs québecois ou belges pour ne reprendre que les plus actifs de ceux qui se réclament de l'extérieur de la France métropolitaine.

#### Les risques

Parler de « francophonie » comporte selon moi le risque d'une confusion : alors que « *French language* » délimite clairement le périmètre, « francophonie » pourrait laisser croire que nous répondons également à des questions du type [travel.SX](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) pour les voyages au sein des pays francophones.

Non, ceci ne me paraît pas souhaitable : à trop diluer ou à offrir trop de redondances avec d'autres SX, les utilisateurs ne peuvent qu'avoir davantage de difficultés à trouver une questions équivalente déjà existante et les répondants auront eux aussi plus de mal à identifier rapidement les questions auxquelles ils peuvent apporter une réponse pertinente.

## Les alternatives

#### Une idée parmi d'autres

Alors existe-t-il une façon de marquer le fait que nous voulons prendre en compte tous les aspects de la langue française ? Peut-être « *French language in Francophone countries* » (puisque c'est là la traduction de « francophonie ») mais cela paraît inutilement lourd. Il est affirmé dans votre codicille qu'il ne s'agit pas d'une tautologie, mais le français est essentiellement parlé dans les pays francophones. Lorsqu'il l'est en-dehors, c'est souvent entre francophones.

#### L'existant

Si on regarde par ailleurs ce qui existe ailleurs sur SX, [english.SX](https://english.stackexchange.com/) a un périmètre semblable au nôtre :

> English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

Comme le français, les usages de l'anglais varient selon les contrées qui l'utilisent. Ces différences sont d'ailleurs je pense plus nombreuses en anglais. Pourtant, leur site ne précise nulle part qu'il s'étend à l'ensemble des pays anglophones.

L'anglais (comme le français) est une langue vivante. Cela implique qu'il existe différentes règles à un moment donné et que celles-ci évoluent.

### Conclusion

**Même si je comprends et j'apprécie la volonté derrière cette proposition, elles ne me semblent pas opportune**.

Je pense que plutôt que de chercher à matérialiser au niveau du site cette volonté, nous pouvons lui donner corps au sein de nos réponses, en cherchant à être aussi exhaustifs que possible et en construisant sur base des réponses de ceux qui connaissent les usages d'autres régions francophones.

Enfin, une autre piste pour mettre en valeur cet aspect de pluralité de la langue et de ses usages au sein du pays serait de représenter la francophonie au sein de la charte graphique du site, dans la mesure du possible et sans rendre le site trop lourd ou indigeste. Cependant, ainsi que l'a indiqué [Gilles](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles), ceci revient entièrement aux employés de SX. En regardant encore une fois l'existant avec [english.SX](https://english.stackexchange.com/), je doute que ceci se concrétise.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ces significations de vote ont été ajoutées après 5 *upvotes*, 0 *downvote*, mais la réponse a toujours clairement été orientée dans ce sens.</sub>

Comment: En fait, il me semble que vous devriez ouvrir une seconde réponse pour le vote FL&U qui recueillerait les votes favorables pour le remplacement de *bêta* par *'& Usage'*. La première réponse totalisant les refus de *'& francophonie'*. L'idée est d'encourager les réponses qui ajoutent  quelque chose à la lecture des dictionnaires et des grammaires, un 'plus' donnant les usages soit 'académiques', soit dans la vie courante ou au bureau, soit argotiques... de simples témoignages de... la francophonie ! --- Les commentaires semblent très favorable à une évolution dans ce sens.